# gnome-tweak-tool not showing any options for customisation

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool, gnome-tweaks

[image]

As you can see that only two options are showing in the gnome tweak tool. All other options are hidden or not showing.

This is happening in Ubuntu 19.10. However, everything is working fine on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximize your Tweaks window. If you don't see left panel then try to `sudo apt purge gnome-tweaks && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

During removing it shows no dependencies, so it seems, the package itself could contain issues or maybe installed not properly or became corrupted during OS using.

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Drag your window to the right to reveal the tab pane on the left. The tab pane contains the different sections. You are now looking to the "General" tab, and that indeed only contains two options.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in VMWare Ubuntu 20.04 and was able to fix it by maximizing and moving the dock to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Just resize the tweak tool window. This will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just wanted to hide my trash icon and my folder but I didn't see the desktop tab. But I soon discovered that you can access it in the extension tab. After that, there will be a desk top icon row, and within that row contains a setting icon button. Just press that button and you will be able to customize your desktop icons.